# How to install pip on Python 3.6.4?

Tags: macos, pip, installation, python-3.6

I've searched through numerous different techniques to install pip on my mac, (Python 3.6.4), but so far none of them have worked. Whenever I try:

```
python get-pip.py
```

After I download get-pip.py, it says that the "get" is invalid syntax

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

It sates here (when I try to get easy-install) that the "$" is invalid, and when I delete it the "apt" is invalid syntax

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
```

Here, again, it says the "$" is invalid, then "easy_install" is invalid syntax

Are there any other ways that might work for me?

Comment: Can you show the exact error? I suspect you're trying to run OS command in a Python command line. Instead you should use OS command line.

Comment: How do I use/get an OS command line?

Comment: Open a terminal. I'm not a mac user but I think the command is `Cmd + T`. Don't copy `$` to the command — `$` is a unix non-root command prompt and included in commands just as a reminder to run commands in a terminal.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.